# Invocation-based Undo Manager in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsundomanager

I'm having trouble adopting the more complex invocation-based approach to undo registration in Swift (based on NSHipster article [here](http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/). Apple's docs still have all sample code in Objective-C, and the semantics are very different for the invocation setup).

My `NSDocument` subclass `Document` has the following method that operates on the model objects, which I wish to make undoable:

```
func rename(object: Any, to newName: String) {
    // This is basically a protocol that requires implementing:
    // var name: String { get set }
    //  
    guard var namedObject = object as? EditorHierarchyDisplayable else {
        return
    }

    // Register undo:
    let undoController = undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as? Document
    undoController?.rename(object: namedObject, to: namedObject.name)
    undoManager?.setActionName("Rename \(namedObject.localizedClassName)")

    // Perform the change:
    namedObject.name = newName
}
```

What I have found out is that `undoController` above is `nil`, becuase the atempted cast to `Document` fails. If I remove the cast (and comment out the call to `undoController.rename(...`), `prepare(withInvocationTarget:)` returns the folowing object:

```
(lldb) print undoController
(Any?) $R0 = some {
 payload_data_0 = 0x00006080000398a0
 payload_data_1 = 0x0000000000000000
 payload_data_2 = 0x0000000000000000
 instance_type = 0x000060800024f0d8
}
(lldb) print undoController.debugDescription
(String) $R1 = "Optional(NSUndoManagerProxy)"
(lldb)
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: The documentation of `prepare(withInvocationTarget:)` says "returns self". `self` is `undoManager`. At the bottom of the NSHipster article it says "This article uses Swift version 1.0.".

Comment: Yes, so do the docs too. But it's casting the returned value to `as ViewController` (I assume this becomes as `Document` in my case). Also, `as` becomes `as?` in Swift 2+

Comment: Casting `NSUndoManager` to `Document` is wrong. Swift 1 didn't care but Swift 3 refuses to do it.

Comment: So, how do I call my `Document` method `rename(object:to:)` on the returned proxy then? Objective-C lets you send any message to any object (at compile time at least), but Swift is strongly typed...

Comment: The blog post has this line of code: `let undoController : ViewController = undoManager?.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self) as ViewController`. How does this translate to Swift 3?

Comment: [How do I register NSUndoManager in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326984/how-do-i-register-nsundomanager-in-swift)

Comment: Yes, I saw that question and was already thinking about using the new API `registerUndoWithTarget<TargetType>(target: TargetType, handler: TargetType -> ())`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic confusion is that `prepare(withInvocationTarget:)` returns a *proxy object* (that happens to be the undo manager itself, but that's an implementation detail). The idea is that you send this proxy object the same message(s) you send to undo the action, but instead of executing them (because it's not the actual object), it internally captures those invocations and saves them for later.

So your code should really start out something like this:

```
let selfProxy: Any = undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self)
```

This works great in Objective-C because the "catchall" type (id) has very lax type checking. But the equivalent `Any` class in Swift is much more stringent and does not lend itself to the same technique, if at all.

See [Using NSUndoManager and .prepare(withInvocationTarget:) in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562636/using-nsundomanager-and-preparewithinvocationtarget-in-swift-3)

Comment: To my surprise, the method used in the answer I linked as "duplicate source", i.e. `(target as AnyObject).methodOfMyTargetClass()` **does** compile without errors or warnings, even though `target` is `AnyObject`, _not_ `MyClass`. I though Swift's strict type system wouldn't allow it to compile. In any case, I moved to the newer, closure-based  `registerUndo(withTarget:handler:)`.

Comment: _"This works great in Objective-C because the "catchall" type (id) has very lax type checking."_ - indeed; I used `NSUndoManager` in Objective-C code in the past.

Comment: For some reason I missed the question/answer you linked; thank you.